# How can I print the data within this xml hierarchy?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm attempting to print out data that is in an XML file. I would like to print out the values for `Ncode`, `Scode` and numbers for `Latitude`/`Longitude`. The file hierarchy looks like this:

```
<root xmlns="rootwebsite.com" schemaVersion="1.0">
  <Ncode="AA">
    <Scode="Y01">
      <Latitude unit="DEGREES">62.0010</Latitude>
      <Longitude unit="DEGREES">-75.6685</Longitude>
    </Scode>
    <Scode="Y02">
      <Latitude unit="DEGREES">62.5210</Latitude>
      <Longitude unit="DEGREES">-75.6785</Longitude>
    </Scode>
  </Ncode>
</root>
```

I have tried using the following script, which prints out the Scode names, however, it only prints out `{rootwebsite}Latitude {'unit': 'DEGREES'}` and `{rootwebsite.com}Longitude {'unit': 'DEGREES'}`, instead of the actual lat/lon values.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse('/Users/jeremy/csites.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root[4]:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
    print(child[0].tag, child[0].attrib)
    print(child[1].tag, child[1].attrib)
```

Comment: The input is not well-formed XML. `<Ncode="AA">` and `<Scode="Y01">` are not proper start tags.

Comment: @mzjn Regardless of its format, is there a simple way to do this or no?